# Why is the Ethereum keystore ciphertext stored in hexadecimal string format only of length 64?

Tags: hex, byte, aes, keystore, ethereum

The ethereum private key is encrypted using aes-128-ctr cipher and stored in the keystore as ciphertext. Output of aes-128-ctr cipher is a hexadecimal string of length 128. Why is the length of the ciphertext stored in keystore as a hexadecimal string only 64?

Answer (score 0):

> Output of aes-128-ctr cipher is a hexadecimal string of length 128.

I believe you're mistaken... shouldn't the output be the same size as the input? An Ethereum private key is 256 bits (32 bytes), so 64 hexadecimal characters sounds right to me.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had another doubt. If the cipher used is aes-128-ctr that is part of the CTR mode, why is there an IV? Isn't IV used for the CBC mode?

Comment: I think an IV is used in all variants of AES: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Counter_(CTR).

Comment: My understanding is that an IV in AES CTR mode is optional. If there is no IV, the counter starts from 1. If we provide an IV, the counter starts from given IV value. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's incorrect. The Wikipedia article I linked to talks about the importance of, in particular, never reusing an IV in CTR mode.

Comment: Isn't it never reusing the IV with the same key?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's correct. So if you intend to use a given encryption key exactly once, it's probably safe to provide an IV that consists solely of zeroes. (I assume that's what you mean by "no IV.") Note that the Wikipedia article says you must take care when using a non-random IV to concatenate, rather than XOR, the IV with the counter. If you're asking these questions because you intend to use AES-128-CTR for something, my advice is to just use a cryptographically random IV. Most libraries will take care of that for you.